# Blank page after installing Mediawiki

Tags: php, installation, mediawiki

I installed Mediawiki by uploading the files to "/wiki" directory then I opened
 "/wiki/mw-config/index.php" and made the configuration and uploaded the "LocalSettings.php" to "/wiki"

when I try to open the wiki using "/wiki/index.php", I see a blank page.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` and `display_error` on your `php.ini`

Comment: I am not running it on my server. I am using a hosting service.

Comment: Add error_reporting( -1 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); to the beginning  of LocalSettings.php

Comment: thank you for replying. The problem was that the generated LocalSettings.php file has an extra html div tag. I thing this is a bug in the Mediawiki. After I removed this tag, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the generated LocalSettings.php file has an extra html div tag. I thing this is a bug in the Mediawiki. After I removed this tag, it worked

Comment: Glad you found the answer and shared it.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Blank_page#You_see_a_Blank_Page:

> A blank white page indicates a PHP error which isn't being printed to the screen. To force this, add the following lines to the LocalSettings.php file, underneath the < ?php: `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );`.
>   You can also set a value for error_log in PHP.ini and read the PHP error log to find out what's going on. In some cases, PHP errors might also be recorded in the web server error log.

In my case, I checked the server error log and found the following line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /path/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php on line NNN, referer: http://wiki.example.com/
```

Which can be fixed by either installing the right `php-xml` package for your distro, or by changing the MediaWiki 'preprocessor' class in LocalSettings.php, as mentioned on the  [WikiMedia Manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms#Fatal_error:_Class_.27DOMDocument.27_not_found_in_xxxxxxxx.2FPreprocessor_DOM.php_on_line_nnn)

Answer (score -1):

I needed to install php-xml and restart httpd. It works great.

Answer (score -3):

I also simply needed to install php-xml and restart httpd.

```
sudo yum install php-xml

sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```